# How can i create an attractive custom navigation bar on the left side of my window as seen in web applications in wpf?

Tags: wpf, navigationbar

Hi I am trying to create a desktop based stand alone application. I want to create a custom navigation bar and place it on left side of my window(i.e. half space goes for navigation bar and another half contains frame element where other pages are hosted). Can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WPF, why not create WPF XBAP application which will have in-built navigation service.

Comment: Hey manish thanks for the reply. What i don't want is to include a browser in my application. I want to create like web based navigation . If i am not wrong i think XBAP is a browser based application. I want to include frame on the right side of my window and then a navigation bar in the left side

Comment: XBAP can work both as a browser appplication as well as a desktop application. The advantage you will have is that you will get IE like backward and forward buttons. But looks like you need all your links on the left side and the related content on the right side. I think you can create a Listview in your left panel and then in the right panel you can add your control based on the selected listviewitem after removing the earlier one

Comment: Do i need to add the items programatically or only through xaml is enough in listview?? Can anyone provide me code??